# AutoCompleteTextView taking so long to reload contacts

Tags: android, contacts

What is wrong with my auto complete contact suggestion it takes 3-4 seconds to complete the loading process. I have around 200 contacts in my phone.  The activity  is for compose message where the user to type/search contacts and write message to send to the recipient.

Inside my oncreate method:

```
mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    SimpleAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcoview,new String[] { "Name", "Phone", "Type" }, new int[] {R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType });
    textView.setThreshold(1);
    textView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
PopulatePeopleList();
```

method to load contacts:

```
public void PopulatePeopleList(){
        int i =0;

        Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (people.moveToNext()){
            String contactName = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String hasPhone = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)){
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,
                null, null);

                while (phones.moveToNext()){
                    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String numberType = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

                    Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                    NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
                    if(numberType.equals("0"))
                        NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Work");
                    else
                        if(numberType.equals("1"))
                            NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Home");
                        else if(numberType.equals("2"))
                            NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Mobile");
                        else
                            NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Other");
                    mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType); //add this map to the list. 
                }
                phones.close();
            }else continue;
        }
        people.close();

    }
```

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for Matiash. This is now my working method and it is very fast compared to above..

```
public void readContacts(){
    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    int colDisplayName = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int colPhoneNumber = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    int colPhoneType = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);

    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String contactName = phones.getString(colDisplayName);
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(colPhoneNumber);
        String numberType = phones.getString(colPhoneType);


        Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
        NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
        NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
        if(numberType.equals("0"))
            NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Work");
        else
            if(numberType.equals("1"))
                NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Home");
            else if(numberType.equals("2"))
                NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Mobile");
            else
                NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Other");
        mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType); //add this map to the list. 
    }phones.close();
}
```

Comment: The widget it's slow when the user types a letter and the results should appear? Post the adapter you have.

Comment: I edited above for my working code... Problem is now solved..Thanks!

Comment: thanx for update man!! save my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a nested loop, which means n queries (as many as you have contacts).

Since apparently you're interested in the phone numbers of **all** contacts, I would suggest iterating only on the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` content provider (without a filter for contact id). The fields you're reading from `Contacts` are also present in that provider.

For example:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

colDisplayName = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int colPhoneNumber = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
int colPhoneType = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);

while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    String contactName = phones.getString(colDisplayName);
    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(colPhoneNumber);
    String numberType = phones.getString(colPhoneType);
    ...
```

This should have much better performance.